# How to customize Paper.js path styles more?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I would like to know if it is possible to customize **path styles** so far that you can immitate such pen stroke styles:

[image]

[image]

Please note: I know that technically I could get these results by positioning multiple shapes densly, but this would be inefficient for a drawing app. Therefore I need a much more efficient solution!